# How do I output a certain line in VB once I have found a string?

Tags: vb.net, windows

What I am trying to do is, find the word "date" in a text file. I have this part working. What I want to do after is to output the entire line that the word "date" was found on.
Any ideas how to this?

```
Heres the code I have so far?



Dim Findline As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("....\resources\" + ShowsCmb.Text + "-desc.txt") 
Dim Dates As String = "date"

If Findline.Contains(Dates) Then 

'Output the line once the word date has been found <<<Here's where the problem is.
Dates.Readline()Dim Dates As String = "date"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```vb
Dim lines as String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)
For Each line as String in lines
    If line.Contains("date") Then
        Console.WriteLine(line)
    End If
End For
```

Comment: This brings a lot of errors.  Besides the console.writeline I want the line to be saved as something like textbox.text. Can't figure out how to get your solution working.

Comment: Just replace filename with the path to your file. If you want to output the line in a textbox just replace `Console.WriteLine(line)` with `TextBox.Text = line`. And I had a typo in my code... Please copy it again.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that out when I get the chance. Can I ask one more thing, I n your code you have, for each line as string. Will that work in vb.